# How to integrate html code in a vue class

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I'm making a search function that filters some cards I have, so if I start typing elephant then it shows only the elephant card.

So I managed to make it work but I wanted to make it a little better and I want to style a little each card and even use font awesome icons but I can't figure out how to do it.

So in my main html file I'm using v-for and v-bind to get the cards from a js file.

code for a card:

```
    class Custcard {constructor(header, info, img, sign) {
    this.header = header;
    this.info = info;
    this.img = img;
    this.sign = sign;
  }}




new Custcard(
    'title',
    'info',
    'imgurl',
    'sign,
```

That works but because each card is a little different, I'm trying to do something Like this:

```
new Custcard(
'<h1>title</h1>',
'<span class="font awesome icon"></span>info',
'imgurl',
'sign,
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Use "moustache" syntax to "interpolate" (i.e. display in place) variable values. For example, `<div>{{info}}</div>` will display the contents of `info` inside the `div` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `v-html` directive.

It would end up looking something like:

```
<div v-for="(card, idx) in cards" v-bind:key="idx" class="card">
    <div class="card-header" v-html="card.header"></div>
    <div class="card-info" v-html="card.info"></div>
    {{ card.img }}
    {{ card.sign }}
</div>
```

or something to that affect.

you can find more info about v-html [on alligator.io](https://alligator.io/vuejs/raw-html-binding/)

Comment: Thank you very much! it's great to have a place like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is prime example of how you can use Vue components. I've made a codepen example here: https://codepen.io/bergur/pen/byYKwd and the explanations are below.

You start of by defining your component. You're describing a card so lets call the component 'card', it should have some propertier like header, info and sign.

```
Vue.component('card', {
  props: ['header', 'info', 'sign'],
  computed: {
    icon() {
      return 'fas fa-'+this.sign
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <i :class="icon"></i> <b>{{ header }}</b> - <em>{{ info }}</em>
    </div>`
})
```

1. The first line defines the name of the component.
2. Then we have the props value which are the properties/attributes of your 
   component.
3. Next we utalize the computed property of a vue object to generate the font-awesome class automatically from the sign props.
4. Finally we define our template, how it should render. I've made this really simple, showing the icon, heading in bold and the info in italics.

Then we define our vue app.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',  
  data() {
    return  {
      title: 'All the cards',
      cardList: [
        {
          header: 'Angry guy',
          info: 'The angry guy is always mad',
          sign: 'angry'
        },
        {
          header: 'Smiley guy',
          info: 'The smiley guy is always really happy',
          sign: 'smile'
        }
      ]
    }
  },  
})
```

1. It hooks the vue app with an element with id="demo"
2. It has a data object which holds the title for our vue app
3. It has a list of all the cards we have defined.
4. Each card has some properties that match the props of our component.

Now we only need to render the app.

```
<div id="demo">
  <h1>{{ title  }}</h1>
  <card v-for="card in cardList" :header="card.header" :info="card.info" :sign="card.sign" />
</div>
```

1. We loop through our cardList with v-for
2. For every card we use the card component

To make the filter, the best way is to

1. Have a computed property called somethin like filteredCardList
2. Create a data property called filter
3. Bind the filter property with the input with v-model
4. Let filteredCardList function filterd version of the cardList array if there's some filter value, otherwise return it unfiltered.
5. Make the v-for loop through filteredCardList